# Change TextView text to Normal after the object has been pressed

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter, android-typeface

I currently have a ListView which uses a CustomAdapter to display the information from my Firebase Database. Which  looks like the following:

[image: ListView]

Upon creation I want the text in the green boxes (The ListView Items) to be bold. Once the user presses on that ListView item I want the text to go to Normal, unbolded.

I want it to work similar to an email. When you get a new email the title is bold and once that email is opened and you go back to your inbox the text is the Normal, unbolded.

The following is all my relevant code:

**MyJobsFragment, SelectItem**

```
// Press the object and display the information and sign the job of with signature pad

    jobListViewMyAcJobs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            ActiveJobDetailsFragment activeJobDetailsFragment = new ActiveJobDetailsFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("Job", adapterActiveJobs.mData.get(position));
            bundle.putSerializable("JobId", adapterActiveJobs.mDataKeys.get(position));
            activeJobDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, activeJobDetailsFragment).addToBackStack(host.getCurrentTabTag()).commit();
        }
    });
```

**MyCustomAdapter**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<JobInformation> mData = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<JobInformation> mDataOrig = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> mDataKeys = new ArrayList<>();

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        ... Removed Code ...

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            // Bid on holder
            MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderBidOn holderBidOn;
            // Accepted holder
            final MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderAccepted holderAccepted;
            // Completed holder
            MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderCompleted holderCompleted;

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                // Bid on
                if (host.getCurrentTab() == 0)
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_bid_on, null);
                    holderBidOn = new MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderBidOn();

                    holderBidOn.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                    holderBidOn.textViewJobDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);

                    holderBidOn.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());
                    holderBidOn.textViewJobDescription.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertDescription());

                    convertView.setTag(holderBidOn);
                }
                // Accepted
                else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 1)
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_accepted, null);
                    holderAccepted = new MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderAccepted();

                    holderAccepted.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                    holderAccepted.textViewDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);

                    holderAccepted.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());
                    if(text != null)
                    {
                        text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    }

                    holderAccepted.textViewDescription.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertDescription());
                    // TODO - Was going to add the the users bid into this here, however it's difficult as the bid isnt stored in the jobs table
                    // TODO - I tried to add it in, looped through the bids table and found the bids with the mDataKeys. But it always displayed the last value.

                    convertView.setTag(holderAccepted);
                }
                // Completed
                else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 2)
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_info_list_completed, null);

                    holderCompleted = new MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderCompleted();

                    holderCompleted.textViewJobName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                    holderCompleted.textViewJobName.setText(mData.get(position).getAdvertName());

                    convertView.setTag(holderCompleted);
                }
            } else
            {
                if (host.getCurrentTab() == 0)
                {
                    holderBidOn = (MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderBidOn) convertView.getTag();
                } else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 1)
                {
                    holderAccepted = (MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderAccepted) convertView.getTag();
                } else if (host.getCurrentTab() == 2)
                {
                    holderCompleted = (MyJobsFragment.MyCustomAdapter.GroupViewHolderCompleted) convertView.getTag();
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        public class GroupViewHolderBidOn
        {
            public TextView textViewJobName;
            public TextView textViewJobDescription;
        }

        public class GroupViewHolderAccepted
        {
            public TextView textViewJobName;
            public TextView textViewDescription;
        }

        public class GroupViewHolderCompleted
        {
            public TextView textViewJobName;
        }
}
```

Comment: can you be a little more clear ? what do you want to do with textview ?

Comment: When the user loads up the screen, the fragment MyJobsFragment, they will be displayed with a ListView such as above, the text surrounded in the green border. If the user hasn't previously opened up the ListView item all the text will be bolded. For example, If I went onto the app all the text such as "New Advert", "New ad" etc will all be bold. When I select and press one of these items in the list such as the top one. It takes me to a new fragment. When I go back to the MyJobsFragment the text is now unbolded, normal as i've opened it up.

Comment: On first viewing, the ListView Items text is all bold. When I then select that list view Item the text goes to normal, unbolded and retains this throughout the application. So later, when I go back to this fragment the text is still unbolded. 

On Outlook a email service. When I get a new email the text of the email is all bold. When I open it up and then go back to my inbox the text is the unbolded, normal with no stylings applied

My question is, how can I replicate this feature in my ListView, in my android application.

Comment: **textview** will be bold before I select it afterwards it will be unbolded

Answer (score 0):

Well there multiple ways of achieving that. I would suggest you to add a field in your `JobInformation` class, something like

```
public class JobInformation{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    . // other fields

    private boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    .
    .
    . // Other getters/setters

}
```

Now you need to set this field when you click an item, in your `onItemClick` function do this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            ActiveJobDetailsFragment activeJobDetailsFragment = new ActiveJobDetailsFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            adapterActiveJobs.mData.get(position).setSelected(true); // add this line in your code
            bundle.putSerializable("Job", adapterActiveJobs.mData.get(position));
            bundle.putSerializable("JobId", adapterActiveJobs.mDataKeys.get(position));
            activeJobDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, activeJobDetailsFragment).addToBackStack(host.getCurrentTabTag()).commit();
        }
```

finally in your `getView` method in your custom adapter, check for `isSelected` field and style your `textview` accordingly, add this in your `getView` method.

```
if(mData.get(position).isSelected()){
    // set your textview typeface to normal
}
else{
    // set your texview typeface to bold.
}
```

and you would need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you update `selected` variable so that your `getView` is called.

Comment: I've been trying to implement this solution above and when I set the isSelected to true for that Item in the List it does change it to true. However, the bold is not changed to normal as the getView in the custom adapter is never recalled. Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: see updated answer. You would need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` , this will cause the `getview` to be called. And `adapter` would be the name of the object of your `MyCustomAdapter` class